# Why can methods be overridden but variables can't?

Tags: java

**Code:**

```
 public class ClassTest {

      public static void main(String args[]) {
           test1 cc = new test2();
           System.out.println(cc.A);
           System.out.println(cc.B);
           cc.method1();
           cc.method2();
      }

 }

 class test1 {
      static int A = 2;
      int B = 5;

      void method1() {
           System.out.println("Inside method 1 test1");
      }

      static void method2() {
           System.out.println("Inside method2 test1");
      }
 }

 class test2 extends test1 {
      static int A = 4;
      int B = 6;

      void method1() {
           System.out.println("Inside method 1 test2");
      }

      static void method2() {
           System.out.println("Inside method 2 test2");
      }
 }
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> 2
>
> 5
>
> Inside method 1 test2
>
> Inside method2 test1

**Question:**

Why are only the methods overridden, but the variables remain unchanged?

Does this behaviour have a name? (like "overriding" for methods)

Comment: The question "why" is tricky - it's because the designers of the language decided to do it like this for reasons of simplicity, efficiency, clarity, etc.

Comment: That's just how the language was designed.  As for why, you'd have to ask the inventors  of Java.

Comment: You are calling a static method from an instance? `static void method2()` -> `cc.method2();`

Comment: Like methods if we had variable behaving in same way, will it cause any issue?

Comment: "Like methods if we had variable behaving in same way, will it cause any issue?" Yes, because code would not behave according to language specification.

Comment: So basically its just the way JAVA is. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened here was that you've used `type1` reference to point to an instance of `test2`. You can do this because `test2` is a type of `test1` - this is called **Polymorphism**.

`test2` is derived from `test1`, so when you create an object of type `test2` you will basically have two objects created, `test2` and `test1` (which will not reside in the heap as an autonomous object).

The JVM will access the **fields** of the object from its reference (because Java is a statically typed language).

So, although, `test2` **hides** both fields of `test1`, when trying to access them from the `test1` reference Java goes automatically to `test1`.

That's about it regarding the fields.

When dealing with methods we have a more complicated issue. Methods are **overridden**, thus, when the method table is built, the methods of `test2` override the methods of `test1`. But, *static* methods are not instance methods.

Thus, when trying to access the static method `method2`, of `test2` from the reference of `test1`, you are "abusing" the code. What you should be doning is calling `test1.method2()` or, if you want to access the static method of `test2` you should use `test2.method2()`.

Hope I explained it well enough...

Answer (score 2):

Overriding a method means let the same method call execute another method body (in the child class).

For a variable "overriding" is unnecessary: you can **overwrite** the variable's value.

Declaring a variable in the child class with the same name *hides* the parent classes variable and introduces an additional field.

For methods to be overridable a special mechanism is needed so that the place in the code may call the method that the actual class of the object specifies. This as opposed to accessing a field.

Answer (score 0):

In Above example you are creating reference of base class that time it will take value A=2,B=5 and it will allocate memory also.so when override to derived class, base class variable hide the derived class variable values that's why it can not override in derived class.

Answer (score 0):

In line: `System.out.println(cc.A);`
This is not the correct way for calling static member, you should always use class name, eg: `System.out.println(test1.A);`

As per the Java specifications, the instance variables are not overridden from a super class by a sub class when it is extended.
Whether the variable be static or nonstatic. Only methods can be overriden.
That's why the output of `cc.A` & `cc.B` is from `test1` class

**For Method Overriding:**
The code `cc.method1();` here overrriding takes place, the object type(i.e the instance of class) actually determines which method is selected at run time, by this object declaration of `new test2()` in this code: `test1 cc = new test2();`
The compiler first checks the method in `test1` class and then it checks in method in `text2` class, if all the signatures (arguments, return types etc) are same then it invokes the sub class method 
since it is overriding the base class method, because actual object is of class `test2`.

**For Static methods:**
Static methods cannot be overridden because method overriding only occurs in the context of dynamic (i.e. runtime) lookup of methods.
Static methods (by their name) are looked up statically (i.e. at compile-time).
thats why the output is from class `test1`.

For "static methods" in Java the exact method to call is determined at compile time.
You explicitly specify the name of the class whose static method you want to execute